# Android E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: env->IsInstanceOf fails E/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0

Tags: android, android-videoview

I am trying to play video song in my app with video-view. But I get nothing except a black screen, and display error 'can't play video'.It seems there are no errors as such in the code except log cat errors which I have never heard of.

```
VideoView videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video_view_ex);

    MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);

    Uri uri= Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Memory Card/Video/Na Na Na Na -DJ 9dip.mp4");
    videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
    videoView.setVideoURI(uri);
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it was because 
`"/Memory Card/Video/Na Na Na Na -DJ 9dip.mp4"`

Is already the path and, as you add `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()` 
It creates a non-valid Uri, because the error you mention is reffered to a inexistent resource. Try leaving it instead:
`Uri uri= Uri.parse("/Memory Card/Video/Na Na Na Na -DJ 9dip.mp4");`